# Missing Intent on real device when <intent-filter> is used

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, sony, sony-xperia

Ok, this question has been asked a number of times on SO, but none of which has solved my issue. Typically most of the others have gone for `BroadcastReceiver` as far as I understand.

Anyway, to the question. One of my Activities should read data from an USB device once it's attached to the phone. In order to perform this I created an `intent-filter` in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file according to the [USB Host guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html), like this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.GetMeterDataActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_get_meter_data" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</activity>
```

This works great in the emulator I use and my `Activity` is started when I attach the device. However, on the real device nothing happens. If I instead register a `BradcastReceiver` as suggested as an alternative solution on the guide the Intent is received and I ask for permission to use it and it works. I however find the later solution less neat since you have to ask permission yourself and would really prefer to just have the `<intent-filter>` in the manifest.

**Tried:**

- I do not use hex values in the `device_filter.xml`.
- Read all relevant posts on SO that I could find but did not find a solution for my issue.
- Moved the `<intent-filter>` between the intended Activity and the `MAIN` Activity without success.
- Logged intent in `onCreate()` and `onResume()`, nothing or just `android.intent.action.MAIN`

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT1:**
This seem to be a Sony issue after upgrading to Lollipop, and devices all of a sudden is blacklisted. I can see this in my logs.

```
09-16 21:23:07.272     860-1279/? W/ContextImpl? Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1346 com.android.server.usb.UsbSettingsManager.blacklistedDeviceAttached:757 com.android.server.usb.UsbHostManager.endUsbDeviceAdded:242 com.android.server.usb.UsbHostManager.monitorUsbHostBus:-2 com.android.server.usb.UsbHostManager.access$000:49
```

If it is indeed blacklisted it's a bit odd that I can still use the device using a `BraodcastReceiver`.

Comment: which device are you using? are you sure that the device have OTG?

Comment: Did not think of that, I got a Sony Xperia Z3 Compact and as far as I can tell it should support OTG. Just tried with a USB memory stick and that one automounts when inserted.

Comment: sometimes (and some devices) even having OTG support, some USB profiles are blocked... like Nexus 7 and USB memory sticks, but controllers, etc works great.

Comment: Good, point. Should read up on OTG. Thanks.

Comment: I am targeting a specific device. Could remove if for test.  That part I guess should be the same in the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Sony that filtered the Intent I wanted to read. With the update to build number 23.4.A.1.232 of the software for Sony Xperia Z3 Compact this is no longer an issue and I receive the Intent.